# Difference between pip's mysql-python and apt-get's python-mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, pip

What is the difference between pip's mysql-python and apt-get's python-mysqldb?

```
$ pip search mysql-python
MySQL-python    - Python interface to MySQL
```

And:

```
$ apt-cache search python-mysqldb
python-mysqldb  - Python interface to MySQL
```

Comment: I think they're the same thing, although they may be different versions. If you've installed Python from the Debian/Ubuntu package, it's probably simplest to use their packaged version of `python-mysqldb` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip should get you the newest version of mysql-python which is available for the version of python that you're using from the pip repository.

Apt will give you the mysql-python version that is deemed "stable" by the debian, or ubuntu repository managers.

The functionality (or security) of the packages could be different based on version differences.

The benefit of using pip install mysql-python, is that you can be using virtualenv and have the specific version installed for that package or framework.